# Nexmo replied SMS captured

Tags: php, laravel, vonage

Signup on Nexmo as free account and able to send the SMS to a particular customer from Nexmo. after that my customer will reply the message, I want to capture the replied message in database by webHooks. and send back SMS to sender mobile number as well.

So Is it possible to capture the replied message on Nexmo. Just wanted to confirm that, I am going to purchase the plan

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.
You'll have to setup a SMS webhook on the number on the Nexmo platform, and Nexmo is going to POST to that webhook with the incoming SMS. The webhook code you write would be responsible for saving that to a database.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Lakatos

Comment: Nexmo respond for single customer SMS or multiple customer SMS about incoming call and message, delivery receipts for message? I means Webhooks returns response per customer or multiple customer?

Comment: Webhook send a POST/GET request per SMS received by the Nexmo number. If you want delivery receipts and calls, need to set up the webhook on the nexmo platform for those as well.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have setup the webhooks for inbound message and dumped the response. but how we know that the replied message is for a unique customer because messageId is coming different if some one replied the message.